# The background of the text doesn't disappear

Tags: html, css, text, background

I was creating a text and I don't know why but the background of the text doesn't disappear. It seems like the background it's stuck in the same color, like it doasn't accept the gradient I create in the box.

I simply created a header and I expected a normal text without background, but I don't know why it doasn't work.

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6MHt.png)
[image]

[CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5UHy.png)
[image]

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDq4v.png)
[image]

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: What are the declarations for the parent container `.nombre_logo`? It would have been easier to copy and paste the HTML & CSS into a snippet for a reproducible example than to post only screenshots

Answer (score 0):

try using `rgb` with alpha as the `background-color` value in the `.nombre_empressa` class.

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

and just adjust the alpha value (`0.5`) based on the transparency you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the class `number_empresa` style contains `backgroud-color` attribute, if so just remove it or give it `transparent` value